# QR CODE android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm developping an android app using Zxing qr code 
But i have a probleme to make a rederction of the web search button to my database
i'm make a modification in this ligne

```
final void openProductSearch(String upc) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google." + LocaleManager.getProductSearchCountryTLD(activity) +"/m/products?q=" + upc + "&source=zxing");
    launchIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
}
```

But nothing it's happen

Comment: Integrate with Intents and just get the result back from ZXing app. Unce you have the result upc you can do whatever you like with it, including making a webservice call to your own db. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google." + 
        LocaleManager.getProductSearchCountryTLD(activity) +
        "/m/products?q=" + upc + "&source=zxing");
```

change localhost by you IP address

Answer (score -2):

if you have the zxing code inside your app , remove that part of the intent and do whatever you need to do with the data . 
you don't have to use the intents part .

zxing has apache licence , so you are free to change the code, as long as you (always , even if you don't touch the code) leave the upper header of the code (with the disclaimer and such) .